# Waiting for resources in Electron

Tags: ajax, phantomjs, electron, headless-browser, nightmare

In PhantomJS we can wait for resources to do something related to AJAX calls of webpage, but in Electron I could not notice such thing, so I want to know is there anything that can help me to handle AJAX calls in Electron.
Is there methods like `waitForUrl` or `waitForResource` from CasperJS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of vanilla Electron you probably meant Nightmare.js?

Comment: I think no difference, but if you know about this case with nightmare that would be great!

Comment: use async/await such as await nightmare.goto(url)

Almost all Nightmare API returns promises which can be awaited

Comment: I am using Nightmare not for testing, but for capturing screenshot where I need to wait for AJAX call on site.
I think only solution in Nightmare is waiting not for resource, but wait some seconds.